# vimでATOMやNotepad++のように、未保存のバッファを次回復元する良い方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: vim

atomやNotepad++などは、前回終了時のタブ（のみためで、ファイル・バッファ）を自動で開く機能があります。

このような振る舞いをvimで簡単に実現できる方法などありましたら教えてください。
※実際には、特定のフォルダや起動方法のときだけでも大丈夫です。
　仕事のメモ書きを手軽に実施したいという話題ですので

auto-saveやsession等でうまくできないかも考えていますので、そのような運用をされている方がありましたら教えていただけると嬉しいです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

Vim 標準の機能でやるならば、session がまさにその目的で使えます。
`:mksession {file}` で現在の状態をセッションファイルに保存できます。
保存されたファイルの実態は Vim script で、ロードすると状態を復元できます。`vim -S {file}` のように Vim を起動することで、状態を復元しつつ Vim を起動できます。
`'sessionoptions'` オプションでどの状態をセッションに保存するかをカスタマイズできます。詳細は `:help 'sessionoptions'` を見てみてください。

セーブとロードを自動で行いたい場合、`autocmd` の設定を vimrc に書くことで実現できると思います。以下はシンプルな設定の例です。(動作確認をしてません。うまく動かなかったらすいません)

```
augroup auto-session
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | source ~/.session.vim | endif
  autocmd VimLeavePre * mksession ~/.session.vim
augroup END
```

もうちょっと凝ったことがしたい場合、セッションの管理をサポートするプラグインなどはたくさんあるので、探してみるといいかもしれません。自動でセーブ/ロードするようなものもあると思います。

---

追記です。
すいません。タイトル部分を見落としていました。
セッションは開いていたファイルを再度開く機能なので、未保存のバッファは復元できません。
Vim で似たようなことをする場合、どこかにメモ用のファイルを用意するのが良いと思います。結局実ファイルが必要になってしまいますが、ATOM などにあるという機能も見えないだけで似たような形でどこかに保存していると思います。
[一時メモを扱うプラグイン](https://github.com/Shougo/junkfile.vim)などもあるので、組み合わせると良いかと思います。

Comment: sessionoptions=blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,options,tabpages,winsize でしたが、:qa!などで抜けた場合の未保存のバッファは復元されないようです。ここでいつも悩んでいます。 autocmdの例ありがとうございます。試してみました。mksession!にしてみて使ってみています。自動保存と組み合わせるほかないでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘通り、ATOMやNotepad++でも実態となるファイルは存在します。Notepad++の場合には、filename@2016-08-11_010233というようなファイルが、なんちゃら/backup/というところに作られるおかげで、「既存のファイルだけれど、未保存の状態」という状態をいつ閉じても実現できる作りになっています。一時メモを扱うプラグインの紹介もありがとうございます。拝見してみます。